# Elasticsearch conditional sorting

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a document with fields part1, part2, part3, part4, part5 which are parts of overall document business id consisting of chars and digits. Sometimes part1-3 is only present, sometimes part4-5, and sometimes all parts. So for example document can have business id:

- 12 AR 1023 where there are three parts: number (part1), string (part2), number (part3)
- XX 421 where there are two parts: string (part4), number (part5)

So in summary this id can have different format and I have to sort those documents. Whats important I cannot concatenate those fields because I would sort by strings, I need to sort them separately because there are numbers and each number field has to be sorted individually, as well as each string part. That means I always need to provide list of fields to sort. The algorithm is: if part4 and part5 are present, sort by part4, part5, otherwise sort by part1, part2, part3.

Is it possible to create a query that would sort all documents in such conditional way ? Or do I need to sort them by part1,part2,part3,part4,part5. In this approach I would sort by part1-3 in the beginning which is wrong, because I need to sort by part4-5 if they are present and omit other parts. But when part4-5 are saved into document I could remove other parts so they would be transparent for all documents having part4-5 only (if part4-5 are present, parts1-3 looses its importance and can be removed if present)

What approach could i use ?

Answer (score 2):

In Elasticsearch, you can achieve conditional sorting using a script-based sorting approach.

Create a script that evaluates the presence of part4 and part5 in each document, sort the documents based on the result of the script. If part4 and part5 are present, sort by part4 and part5; otherwise, sort by part1, part2, and part3.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """
            if (doc['part4.keyword'].size() > 0 && doc['part5.keyword'].size() > 0) {
              return [doc['part4.keyword'].value, doc['part5.keyword'].value];
            } else {
              return [doc['part1.keyword'].value, doc['part2.keyword'].value, doc['part3.keyword'].value];
            }
          """
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this example sorts fields separatelly ? Some of them are strings, other numbers, so I cannot concatenate those fields. Are u concatenating them in your example ? Would it be then a string sorting ? Then number part would not be sorted correctly

Comment: Using Elasticsearch, we can sort documents conditionally based on the presence of certain fields. We don't need to concatenate fields into a single string for sorting. Instead, we can use a script-based sorting approach. If part4 and part5 exist, we sort by them. If not, we sort by part1, part2, and part3. This ensures correct sorting based on field types and the document's structure.

Comment: And why did u specify script type: number ?

Comment: ","lang":"painless","position":{"offset":56,"start":31,"end":81},"caused_by":{"type":"class_cast_exception","reason":"Cannot cast from [java.util.ArrayList] to [double]."}}}]},"status":400}

Comment: Ignore the type field, it's not relevant here. My mistake. For clarity, I've added "lang": "painless" to the script

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible with org.elasticsearch library 7.17.14 in my case because  type seems to be obligatory and possible values are string, number: public ScriptSortBuilder(Script script, ScriptSortBuilder.ScriptSortType type) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(script, "script cannot be null");
        Objects.requireNonNull(type, "type cannot be null");
        this.script = script;
        this.type = type;
    }